# Marketing Cloud REST API Certificate Renewal

Tags: marketing-cloud

hope many of you have received the email today.

Can anyone help me understand what is the change made here and what is a TSL certificate!

Can anyone summaries what are the list of checks to be done within MC.

Does it impact any current existing API triggered journeys?

How do I find out that my account is using a TSL certificate configured.

Comment: send a ticket to Salesforce. They are your best bet

Comment: How is the something you should be asking on StackOverflow instead of just asking your Account Executive at Salesforce?

Comment: Hi all thanks for your feedback. However I understand this should be the question to Salesforce AE. But though I had been working on SFMC for 4+ years I have never had to or could even came to know about TSL! ... so just wanted to check if this is something related to the `KEY MANAGEMENT` feature of SFMC....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything unless you have been *storing or caching* the certificate anywhere (some tools/frameworks require this).

Btw: The email itself should be mentioning in which case an action is required.

Comment: thanks for the above info. As mentioned above `(some tools/frameworks require this).` can you please share some examples.